# XML dynamic line removal in attribute-based using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a complex and very large xml where i should scour the last level of each line and remove that line (or the whole grouper with the line) if the line attribute is less than a specified value.

for example, below is a sample of the XML, I have to look at each line of "Op" element to see if the DtContrat attribute is < than "2021-01-01" , if smaller, I should remove the line with "Op" element and whatever is being grouped by it, however, if the parent line (Cli) there is only one "Op" element and it is removed, I must also remove the entire "Cli" element

```
<Doc3040 DtBase="2021-11" CNPJ="12345678" TotalCli="3" Remessa="1" Parte="1" TpArq="F" NomeResp="Alexander" EmailResp="alexander@alexander.com.br" TelResp="123456789">
        <Cli Cd="13245678912" Tp="1" Autorzc="N" PorteCli="0" IniRelactCli="2020-09-25" ClassCli="A" FatAnual="0.01">
            <Op Contrt="123456" IPOC="132456789123456789123456789" Mod="0218" Cosif="3096000" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="0000000" TaxEft="790.7188400" DtContr="2020-04-25" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-04-25" ClassOp="H" DiaAtraso="189" CaracEspecial="19">
                <Inf Tp="0399"/>
            </Op>
            <Op Contrt="123456" IPOC="132456789123456789123456780" Mod="0210" Cosif="3096000" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="0000000" TaxEft="790.7188400" DtContr="2021-05-15" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-10-25" ClassOp="H" DiaAtraso="189" CaracEspecial="19">
                <Inf Tp="0399"/>
            </Op>
        </Cli>
        <Cli Cd="12345678913" Tp="1" Autorzc="N" PorteCli="0" IniRelactCli="2019-06-27" ClassCli="A" FatAnual="0.01">
            <Op Contrt="123457" IPOC="132456789123456789123456788" Mod="0210" Cosif="1612022" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="88117400" TaxEft="59.9200000" DtContr="2020-09-23" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-03-10" ClassOp="A" ProvConsttd="1.30" DtaProxParcela="2021-12-10" VlrProxParcela="96.87" QtdParcelas="5">
                <Venc v110="96.87" v140="35.95" v130="34.58" v120="93.52"/>
            </Op>
        </Cli>
        <Cli Cd="12345678914" Tp="1" Autorzc="N" PorteCli="0" IniRelactCli="2019-11-23" ClassCli="A" FatAnual="0.01">
            <Op Contrt="132458" IPOC="132456789123456789123456787" Mod="0204" Cosif="1612020" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="88117400" TaxEft="790.7188400" DtContr="2021-11-10" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-12-10" ClassOp="A" ProvConsttd="0.00" VlrContr="0.03">
                <Venc v110="0.03"/>
            </Op>
        </Cli>
    </Doc3040>
```

the expected result of the above xml would be as follows

```
<Doc3040 DtBase="2021-11" CNPJ="12345678" TotalCli="2" Remessa="1" Parte="1" TpArq="F" NomeResp="Alexander" EmailResp="alexander@alexander.com.br" TelResp="123456789">
    <Cli Cd="13245678912" Tp="1" Autorzc="N" PorteCli="0" IniRelactCli="2020-09-25" ClassCli="A" FatAnual="0.01">
        
        <Op Contrt="123456" IPOC="132456789123456789123456780" Mod="0210" Cosif="3096000" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="0000000" TaxEft="790.7188400" DtContr="2021-05-15" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-10-25" ClassOp="H" DiaAtraso="189" CaracEspecial="19">
            <Inf Tp="0399"/>
        </Op>
    </Cli>
    <Cli Cd="12345678914" Tp="1" Autorzc="N" PorteCli="0" IniRelactCli="2019-11-23" ClassCli="A" FatAnual="0.01">
        <Op Contrt="132458" IPOC="132456789123456789123456787" Mod="0204" Cosif="1612020" OrigemRec="0199" Indx="11" PercIndx="0.00" VarCamb="790" CEP="88117400" TaxEft="790.7188400" DtContr="2021-11-10" NatuOp="01" DtVencOp="2021-12-10" ClassOp="A" ProvConsttd="0.00" VlrContr="0.03">
            <Venc v110="0.03"/>
        </Op>
    </Cli>
</Doc3040>
```

notice that in the Doc3040 element I also needed to update the "TotalCli" attribute with the new "Cli" element total from the file

**I researched and saw that it is possible to do this using XSL, but I have no knowledge of this language, could anyone help me coding this XSL code?**

Comment: If you've not tried, you're not ready to ask.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: I tried it, but XSL is complex and very different for me, I stopped programming a long time ago and I'm going to use it in a pentaho step. I've started some tutorials, but they're very simple, and from what I've seen the XSL code to do this it's all going to be pretty complex, and I've got a short deadline to resolve. but thanks anyway

Comment: You need to check XSLT **Identity Transform** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with specialized templates.

The second (empty) template matches the `Op` elements that have `@DtContr` values less than the `$cutoff-date` and `Cli` elements that do not have any `Op` with `@DtrContr` values greater than the `$cutoff-date`. Since that template doesn't produce any content, the items that it matches are excluded from the output.

The third template matches the `Doc3040/@TotalCli` and produces an attribute with the same name, but a value that counts the number of `Cli` that have `Op/@DtContr` values greater than `$cutoff-date`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
  <xsl:param name="cutoff-date" select="'2021-01-01'"/>
    
  <!--this is the identity template that by default copies all content-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <!--more specific templates can be used to match certain content and override the default behavior-->
  <xsl:template match="Cli[not(Op[@DtContr gt $cutoff-date])] | Op[@DtContr lt $cutoff-date]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Doc3040/@TotalCli">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="count(../Cli[Op[@DtContr gt $cutoff-date]])"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An alternative solution that consolidates some of the logic and tests:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:param name="cutoff-date" select="'2021-01-01'"/>
       
    <!--this is the identity template that by default copies all content-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--more specific templates can be used to match certain content and override the default behavior-->
    <xsl:template match="Doc3040">
        <xsl:variable name="Cli-after-cutoff-date" as="element(Cli)*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Cli"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!--prune the Cli that had all of their Op dropped -->
        <xsl:variable name="Cli-after-cutoff-date-filtered" select="$Cli-after-cutoff-date[Op]" as="element(Cli)*"/>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="TotalCli" select="count($Cli-after-cutoff-date-filtered)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @TotalCli"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$Cli-after-cutoff-date-filtered"/>
        </xsl:copy>
         
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="Op[@DtContr lt $cutoff-date]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another solution, likely to perform the best, would be to use [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#xsl-key):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:param name="cutoff-date" select="'2021-01-01'"/>
    <xsl:key name="Op-after-cutoff" match="Op[@DtContr gt $cutoff-date]" use="generate-id(..)"/>
    
    <!--this is the identity template that by default copies all content-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Doc3040">
        <xsl:variable name="Cli-filtered" as="element(Cli)*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Cli"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="TotalCli" select="count($Cli-filtered)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @TotalCli"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$Cli-filtered"/>
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Cli">
        <xsl:variable name="Op-filtered" select="key('Op-after-cutoff', generate-id(.))"/>
        <xsl:if test="$Op-filtered">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$Op-filtered"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am not going to work on this - but if I were, I would be looking for a way to test each node once instead of three times.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Good point. Was just looking to satisfy the requirements, but with larger docs it may not be the most performant. I have added some additional solutions. `xsl:key` (not surprising) seems to win out.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Mads, i will work on it